# Exchanging values in rows in R

Tags: r

I wanted to exchange the V2 and V3 values in each row when the left value is bigger then the right value? So the bigger value should be in V3 and the smaller in V2.

```
V1    V2           V3 
3     113634042   112634042    
15    42130650    43130646    
5     59947488    60947483    
47    65968160    66968149    
16    30674811    29674823    
5     10441822    9441835
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `pmin` and `pmax` for that task. They will return a vector of the length of the number of rows, one with the minimum values between the second and the third column, one with the maximum values. Then we replace the original 2 columns by the new values :

```
df[,2:3]<-cbind(pmin(df[,2],df[,3]),pmax(df[,2],df[,3]))

df
#   V1        V2        V3
# 1  3 112634042 113634042
# 2 15  42130650  43130646
# 3  5  59947488  60947483
# 4 47  65968160  66968149
# 5 16  29674823  30674811
# 6  5   9441835  10441822
```

DATA :

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(3L, 15L, 5L, 47L, 16L, 5L), V2 = c(113634042L, 
42130650L, 59947488L, 65968160L, 30674811L, 10441822L), V3 = c(112634042L, 
43130646L, 60947483L, 66968149L, 29674823L, 9441835L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

An other option is to use `apply` and `sort` :

```
t(apply(df[,2:3],1,sort))
#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 112634042 113634042
# [2,]  42130650  43130646
# [3,]  59947488  60947483
# [4,]  65968160  66968149
# [5,]  29674823  30674811
# [6,]   9441835  10441822
```

The `apply` version appears to be slower than `pmin` and `pmax` :

```
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  pmax  54.202  57.089  68.17331  68.4750  72.0025  167.738   100  a 
 apply 561.263 581.950 624.66715 598.4675 630.5395 1179.936   100   b
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `transform` along with `pmin` and `pmax`:

```
transform(DF, V2 = pmin(V2, V3), V3 = pmax(V2, V3))
```

giving:

```
  V1        V2        V3
1  3 112634042 113634042
2 15  42130650  43130646
3  5  59947488  60947483
4 47  65968160  66968149
5 16  29674823  30674811
6  5   9441835  10441822
```

**Note:** Here is the data in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "3     113634042   112634042    
15    42130650    43130646    
5     59947488    60947483    
47    65968160    66968149    
16    30674811    29674823    
5     10441822    9441835"


DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a data.table solution, editing the columns by reference (copied etienne's dataset):

```
library(data.table)


df <- structure(list(V1 = c(3L, 15L, 5L, 47L, 16L, 5L), V2 = c(113634042L, 
42130650L, 59947488L, 65968160L, 30674811L, 10441822L), V3 = c(112634042L, 
43130646L, 60947483L, 66968149L, 29674823L, 9441835L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

dtable <- data.table(df)

dtable[,c('V2','V3') := .(ifelse(V2 > V3, V3, V2), ifelse(V2 > V3, V2, V3))]
```

Comment: Ah, I just had the inequality switched

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace the rows with wrong order, with the same rearranged rows:

```
df[df$V2>df$V3,2:3] = df[df$V2>df$V3,3:2]
```